# Double Values Not Showing Calculated Values

Tags: double

I'm trying to calculate the payment term for the user. I try to crunch the numbers and spit them out, but that's not happening for some reason. However, it displays perfectly fine when I explicitly assign the variables a value while declaring them.

```
public static void creditCardPaymentCalculator()
   {
                    //User Input Variables
         Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

                    //User's Input
         double purchaseAmount, interestAmount = 0, minimumMonthlyPayment;

                    //Table Counters
         int[] month = new int[12];
         double payment = 0;
         double monthlyInterest = 0;
         double principal = 0;
         double remainingBalance = 0;

         double yearsOfPayment = 0;

         int yearCounter = 1;
         int monthCounter = 0;


                                //Initialize Variables
         //-------------------------------------------------------------------------

                   //Initialize Month Array
         for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
         {
             month[i] = (i + 1);
         }



         //-------------------------------------------------------------------------




                   //Welcome Message
         System.out.println("\n\n\n\nCredit Card Payment Calculator\n\n");

                    //Get User Input
         System.out.println("Enter Your Purchase Amount");
         purchaseAmount = userInput.nextDouble();
         System.out.println("Enter Interest Amount");
         interestAmount = userInput.nextDouble();
         System.out.println("Enter Minimum Monthly Payment");
         minimumMonthlyPayment = userInput.nextDouble();

                    //Calculate Input For Chart (Not Working)
         payment = minimumMonthlyPayment;
         monthlyInterest = (((interestAmount / 100) * remainingBalance / yearsOfPayment) / 12);
         principal = payment - monthlyInterest;
         remainingBalance = remainingBalance - principal;

                  //Calculate Number Of Years For Payment
         yearsOfPayment = (((interestAmount / 100) * remainingBalance) + remainingBalance) / minimumMonthlyPayment;





                    //Output
         System.out.printf("\n     Year: %d/%.0f", yearCounter, yearsOfPayment);


         System.out.printf("\nMonth     Payment     Interest      Principal      Remaining Balance");
         System.out.printf("\n%d         %.2f        %.2f          %.2f           %.2f", month[monthCounter], payment, monthlyInterest, principal, remainingBalance);

                    //Increment Counters
         monthCounter++;
         if (month[monthCounter] == 12)
         {
             yearCounter++;
                 //Reset monthCounter
             monthCounter = 0;
         }



                    //Line Spacing
         System.out.printf("\n\n\n\n\n");


   }
```

Comment: What specifically does "that's not happening" mean? What part is not working for you? Expecting us to copy, paste, and run your code to even figure out what you're asking is a little inconsiderate. You already know what the issue is you're looking for help with; it's much better if you just go ahead and tell us.

Comment: They "won'" what? :-) Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14838750/edit) your question and explain what the problem is that you're having, so we can try and help you solve it.

Comment: The variables in which I calculated a value won't display any value in my printf statements. Those variables will display a value in my printf statements, however, if I initialize them as soon as they are declared. Let me know if you need another explanation.